Complex plane regions through Möbius transformation

Sketch the region of the complex plane
$$A:=\{z \in \Bbb C : 1<|z|<4 \}$$
and graphically represent $f(A)$ where
$$f(z) = \frac{4-2z}{z+1}$$


While I have no problem sketching $A$ that I think is the region between circles of radius $1$ and $4$ centered in the origin so 
I'm having some issues for the second part. I think it's a Möbius transformation because it's in the form
$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{ca+d}, \qquad ad-bc \neq 0$$
So what I've done is first determine where $D(0,1)$ goes and since $f(-1) = \infty, f(1) = 1$, I think
$$D(0,1) \to \{\Re(z) = 1\}$$
and I have a feeling that the rest goes in a strip of the complex plane so I search for a lower bound and $f(-4) = -4$.
Therefore I think $f(A) $

but I'm not completely sure. Any help appreciated!

There’s no reason to assume the image is a strip as you suggest

Check all four real values. The inner circle is mapped to a line because $-1$  is sent to $\infty$  However, the outer circle is sent to some other circle, also symmetric across the real axis, because all coefficients are real.  That is, here $f(\bar z) = \bar{f(z)}.$ And that is why the line has constant real part.....What is $f(4) ? $

HINT…
set $$w=u+iv=\frac{4-2z}{z+1}$$
$$\implies z=\frac{4-w}{w+2}$$
Then, the inequality for $z$ becomes $$1<\left| \frac{4-w}{w+2}\right|<4$$
The left hand side reduces to $u<1$ and the right hand side reduces to the region outside a circle which I expect you can find quite easily.

I found $\bigg(u+\frac{12}{5}\bigg)^2+v^2 > \frac{64}{25}$. So what is happening is the inner circle is send to a line and the outer circle to that circle above. The region that before the transformation was outside of $|z|>4$ now is inside, am I right?

So the region is to the left of the line $x=1$ and outside the circle you have found.

You can break down this transformation into simple steps to more easily visualize what's going on. Let
$$f_1(z) = z + 1$$
$$f_2(z) = 1/z$$
$$f_3(z) = 6z - 2$$
Then $f(z) = (f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1)(z)$, and now we have an inversion step ($f_2$) along with two simple affine transformations.
The first step is simply a translation by $1$ to the right. The inversion step is more complicated to visualize:

First remember that the inversion will swap points far from the origin with points near it, so we should expect the outer circle of radius 4 (and everything outside it) to be mapped within the image of the inner circle of radius $1$ (and the image of everything inside it).
The image of any circle through the origin is a line not through the origin; in particular, the inner circle (radius $1$) in your first graph will be through the origin once we translate it $1$ unit to the right. The image is easy to visualize by checking $f_2(2)$ and $f_2(\pm 1 + i)$.
The image of any circle not through the origin is another circle. In this case, the circle centered at $1$ of radius $4$ is entirely outside the unit circle, hence its image will be entirely contained inside the unit circle. Again, by checking points like $f_2(-3)$ and $f_2(5)$ you can see what it looks like and trivially calculate the center and radius.

This is enough to draw a picture of the image of $f_2 \circ f_1$, and then it is straightforward to scale and translate it using $f_3$.

To work with Möbius transformations in general, decompose them into the following steps:

$z \mapsto z + \frac{d}{c}$
$z \mapsto 1/z$
$z \mapsto -\frac{ad - bc}{c^2}z$
$z \mapsto z + \frac{a}{c}$

You can check yourself that the composition is equivalent to
$$z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$$
See Chapter 3 of Visual Complex Analysis by Needham for a great overview of these transformations.

I'm finding this new point of view very interesting, also the lecture you're suggesting. It's not very clear your answer though since I'm trying to make te composition you write above but I get $f(z) = \frac{6z-1}{2(3z-1)}$ that is not my $f(z)$...

@TurquoiseTilt you are composing backwards. It should be $f = f_3(f_2(f_1(z)))$.

$z \xrightarrow {f_1} z+1 \xrightarrow {f_2} 1/z + 1 = \frac{z+1}{z}\xrightarrow {f_3} \frac{6z - 2 +1}{6z-2 } = \frac{6z-1}{2(3z-1)}$ or do you mean that I should start with $f_3$ because in that case for me the composition $f = f_1(f_2(f_3(z)))$ is what I'm used to

In your second step, don’t replace $z$ with $1/z$, apply $f_2$ to the whole expression. so you get $1/(z + 1)$.

Oh I see! it's $f_2(f_3(z)) = f_2(z+1)$, now everything works fine!
